# Is there a cleaner way to achieve curve fitting with multiple models?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, lmfit

In my project I have multiple family of functions predefined to fit a curve. Let's look at the simplest:

```py
def polyfit3(x, b0, b1, b2, b3):
    return b0+b1*x+b2*x**2+b3*x**3

def polyfit2(x, b0, b1, b2):
    return b0+b1*x+b2*x**2

def polyfit1(x, b0, b1):
    return b0+b1*x
```

*Note:
I know that in this particular case [`np.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) would be a better choice*

The (much more simplyfied) function, which makes the fitting looks like this:

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
try:
    from lmfit import Model
    _has_lmfit = True
except ImportError:
    _has_lmfit = False

def f(x, y, order=3):
    if _has_lmfit:
        if order == 3:
            fitModel = Model(polyfit3)
            params = fitModel.make_params(b0=0, b1=1, b2=1, b3=1)
            result = fitModel.fit(y, x=x, params=params)
        elif order == 2:
            fitModel = Model(polyfit2)
            params = fitModel.make_params(b0=0, b1=1, b2=1)
            result = fitModel.fit(y, x=x, params=params)
        elif order == 1:
            fitModel = Model(polyfit1)
            params = fitModel.make_params(b0=0, b1=1)
            result = fitModel.fit(y, x=x, params=params)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Order is out of range, please select from [1, 3].')
    else:
        if order == 3:
            popt, pcov = curve_fit(polyfit3, x, y)
            _function = polyfit3
        elif order == 2:
            popt, pcov = curve_fit(polyfit2, x, y)
            _function = polyfit2
        elif order == 1:
            popt, pcov = curve_fit(polyfit1, x, y)
            _function = polyfit1
        else:
            raise ValueError('Order is out of range, please select from [1, 3].')
    # more code there.. mostly working with the optimized parameters, plotting, etc.
```

My problem is this gets really ugly quickly and I repeat myself over and over again. Is there a way to build this better?

**EDIT**:

I've tried this:

```py
def poly_fit(x, *args):
    return sum(b*x**i for i, b in enumerate(args))

...

fitModel = Model(poly_fit)
fitModel.make_params(**{f'b{i}': 1 for i in range(order+1)})
```

but unfortunately lmfit throws an error:

```py
ValueError: varargs '*args' is not supported
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `lmfit.models.PolynomialModel()` does exactly what you are looking for.  That model takes the polynomial degree `n` as an argument and uses coefficients named `c0`, `c1`, ..., `cn` (handling up to `n=7`):

```
from lmfit.models import PolynomialModel

def f(x, y, degree=3):
    fitModel = PolynomialModel(degree=degree)
    params = fitModel.make_params(c0=0, c1=1, c2=1, c3=0, 
                                  c4=0, c5=0, c6=0, c7=0)
    # or if you prefer to do it the hard way:
    params = fitModel.make_params(**{'c%d'%i:0 for i in range(degree+1)})

    return fitModel.fit(y, x=x, params=params)
```

Note that it is OK to over-specify coefficients here.  That is, if `degree=3`, that call to `fitModel.make_params(c0=0, ..., c7=0)` will actually not make parameters for `c4`, `c5`, `c6`, or `c7`.

`PolynomialModel` will raise a `TypeError` if `degree > 7`, so I left your explicit test for that out.

I hope that gets you started, but it does seem like you might have wanted to include other model functions too.   In a case like that, what I have done is to make a dictionary of class names:

```
from lmfit.models import LinearModel, PolynomialModel, GaussianModel, ....

KnownModels = {'linear': LinearModel, 'polynomial': PolynomialModel, 
              'gaussian': GaussianModel, ...}
```

and then use that to construct the model:

```
modelchoice = 'linear' # probably really came from user selection in a GUI

if modelchoice in KnownModels:
    model = KnownModels[modelchoice]()
else:
    raise ValueError("unknown model '%s'" % modelchoice)

params = model.make_params(....) # <- might know and store what the parameter names are
.....
```

Comment: This seems good. What options do I have if I want to use a model which is (most probably) not predefined like ```PolynomialModel```? For example this family, where only the cosine's argument changes : ```c0 + c1 * np.cos(c2 + c3*x)```, ```c0 + c1 * np.cos(c2 + c3*x + c4*x**2 )```, ...

Comment: I would expect you would want to have a model function with "null" default values for all arguments (probably `cN=0`, but maybe `cN=-np.inf`) and wrap that within a `lmfit.Model` class.  The code for `PolynomialModel` might be a useful example to follow.  Also: try to use more meaningful parameter names where possible (`c0` => `offset`, `c1` => `amplitude`, `c2` => `phase_offset`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite your code by creating global config for your `polyfit` functions. This is more pythonic version of `if`.

```py
polyfits = {
    1: {
        'f': polyfit1,
        'params': ['b0', 'b1'],
        'vals'  : [  0,    1], 
    },
    2: {
        'f': polyfit2,
        'params': ['b0', 'b1', 'b2'],
        'vals'  : [   0,    1,   1,], 
    },
    3: {
        'f': polyfit3,
        'params': ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
        'vals'  : [   0,    1,    1,    1], 
    },

}

def f(x, y, order=3):
    if order not in polyfits.keys():
        raise ValueError('Order is out of range, please select from {}.'.format(','.join(map(str, polyfits.keys()))))
    _function = polyfits[order]['f']
    if _has_lmfit:
        fitModel = Model(_function)
        params = dict(zip(polyfits[order]['params'], polyfits[order]['vals']))
        params = fitModel.make_params(**params)
        result = fitModel.fit(y, x=x, params=params)
    else:
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(_function, x, y)
```

I believe you post *very* simplified version of your code (because your current version could be minimized more effectively than my code above).

Comment: Yes indeed, this is a very simplified code and as I mentioned this could be a ```np.polyfit```. But also I have much more advanced ones where I cannot use ```np.polyfit```. My goal is to find a cleaner way of doing this. I'll check out that code you posted and see how it scales up.

Comment: For scaling you should change only `polyfits` section (and maybe generate it programmatically).